# NodeJS crypto module not working in browser after bundling with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, cryptojs

I keep getting the following error when I view my code in the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: crypto.createHash is not a function

I've tried loading the module during runtime using webpack:

```json
module.exports = {
  target: "web",
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./dist/index.js",
  output: { filename: "../dist/bundle.js" },
  externals: { crypto: require("crypto") }, <=== here
};
```

and importing as: `import * as crypto from "crypto"`, but this leads to the same error outlined above.

I realize that the browser has its own native `crypto` API and thus also tried aliasing the name to a different name like `import * as crypt from "crypto"`, however this leads to the same error.

Repository with full code is available: https://www.github.com/lbragile/LibraCoin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js core libraries are **only** available in node.js environments. So, if at the end, you will run your code in browser, you *cannot* use node core libraries.

Note that crypto is a **core library**

Browser crypto API is completely different as far as I know. So check out its [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto)

Comment: So my only option would be to communicate with a server?

Unfortunately, Web Crypto API does not have the features that I need with the appropriate algorithm ("SHA256").

Comment: not sure but I found this, worth checking out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest In general, check out subtle crypto interface

Comment: this looks promising thank you so much! Will let you know if it works.

Comment: This works!!!

API says that you must have a secure connection to use these functions, but localhost is considered secure.

Thank you so much!